# Why does the Inductance change on an E-Core Leg when going from Small Copper Wire to Litz Wire?

Tags: transformer, inductance, coil, ferrite, litz-wire

In the first picture you can see 45 turns of standard 0.4 mm copper wire. The impedance analyzer (e4990) shows an inductance at 20 kHz of 11.5 mH. Which is inside the tolerance of around 12.8 mH +- 20%.

The impedance analyzer measures Ls and Rs, which is the equivalent series resistance and inductance of the impedance at a given frequency.

[image: 45 turns of 0.4 diameter copper wire on an E100]

However, using the following litz wire coil:

[image: Rupalit 3.05x3.05 safety profile, 1260x0.071 (overkill for 20 kHz)]

Measured the same way on the same core:

[image: E100 Core with litz wire 45 turns]

Gives only around 8.2 mH. How is this even possible? I have gone through simulations, lots of models that could possibly cause this, asked some Phds but I can't answer such a huge deviation.

Here is what I already thought of:

Any capacitance can't be the cause of this, since for lower frequencies we see the same inductance value (also evident in circuit simulation).

The air between the core legs can cause huge deviations, but when it is pressed down with a clamp we get the same results.

Even if I missed a turn on the litz wire coil, it wouldn't cause such huge change (44^2/45^2).

Very high quality litz wire (3.05x3.05 mm 1280 x 0.071mm rupalit safety) -> impossible for shorts, which could have explained lower inductance.

Has anyone seen this before or are there papers on this?

Edit:

Here is the same measurement at home giving 11.17 mH.: [image]

Now I added 45 turns of thinner copper wire but with huge gaps to increase leakage as requested by @tobalt:
[image]

As you can see leakage is increased by about 0.4 mH. Which in context to the original problem makes the litz wire measurement further implausible.

Comment: That impedance analyzer should be doing well at that frequency and that value of inductance. The only thing I can think of- and I don't see why it changes the measurement- do you have good solid connections to all the Litz strands? What are the measured Rs values?

Comment: @Fred Oh sorry, the Rs value seems to be parallel resistance. For series resistance I used a multimeter and measured less than 250 mOhm. I ensured good connection by using a solder bath to melt all ends together, and also looked at its cross section, which was nicely soldered.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to share the reasons for the downvote?  Seems like a valid question and plenty of investigation before posting IMO

Comment: Also I should mention: This change also appears on 6 similar wound coils. So it is not just a defective singular coil.

Comment: I can't see anything in the first picture; could you submit larger pictures, or more closely cropped to show the subject?

Comment: @TimWilliams I enlarged them. If there is anything you need to know in particular, I will provide, thanks.

Comment: > the Rs value seems to be parallel resistance.???    Usually the measurement options are Rseries/ Lseries and Cparallel/Rparallel. When set for Rs/Ls, does the instrument provide a plausible measurement?

Comment: @Fred Good point, for some reason I turned a blind eye on the resistance measurement.  I looked up the E4990 Help Page: "Equivalent series inductance Equivalent series resistance Ls - Rs". Then intuitively the Rs measurement of 5.2 Ohm seems wrong for the 0.4mm copper wire version. I will think about it for a minute.

Comment: The series resistance is simply the real value of the complex impedance. Since there is parallel capacitance, as we increase frequency we come close to resonance, which results in higher impedance. And doing a quick spice simulation shows the exact same behaviour. What doesn't change however, is the inductance :( It should almost only go up as we come closer to resonance.

Comment: Try winding the coil on a cardboard form that fits loosely over the leg, try two diameters, and try moving it around, rather than accumulating just around the corner. How does inductance vary in those cases?

Comment: @TimWilliams We can disregard two layers, since when I removed the second litz layer I received 1/4 the inductance, which is consistent (but still too low). I will try the cardboard trick tomorrow. Also on monday when Im back at the lab, I'm going to put a series resistor in front of the coil, to emulate the higher resistance of the thin wire. This would show that the analyzer is not accurate for low series resistance.

Comment: For the same complex impedance the equivalent inductance and resistance will *both* be different depending on the model (series or parallel) that you use.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes you are correct. I'm mainly just talking about the series circuit. My argument is, that the equivalent inductance can never be lower if you account for parasitics at low frequencies (below resonance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As core was inserted into winding with 3d printed bobbin, some insides of the 3d printed material was scraped off and landed right between the core halfes creating an air gap lowering the effective permeability. Next time print the bobbins with more space inside!

Answer (score 2):

For 0.4mm magnet wire, you have tight winding over the core with no gap. The litz wire looks 10x thicker, has additional jacket, and comes on a bobbin with thick walls. So the geometry of wires is totally different, coil-to-coil coupling is different. Nearly everything is different. Why would you expect the same inductance?

If you try a copper wire of the same as litz diameter over the same bobbin, I am sure your results will be much closer.

Comment: Well if anything I would expect the litz wire coil to have higher inductance. You mentioned the coil geometry, which because of air gaps should increase the leakage inductance. The total inductance is then the sum of leakage and magnetization inductance, which should be very slightly bigger than the 0.4 mm version.

Comment: @cu29p, not sure about your "leakage inductance", but from simple physics it should be obvious that the outer layers of your litz bobbin are far from magnetic core, so the effective inductance factor (AL) for these outer layer turns is lower than if the wire would tightly wound on the core (as it is in 0.4mm copper). That's why your litz inductance is lower.

Comment: @cu29p can you make a cross-check: Take any wire, and make a deliberately bad/loose winding -> check if inductance drops even more.

Comment: If all "things" were the same, "Litz wire" would have a lower resistive part and Q would be higher for the same "inductance" ...

Comment: @tobalt I added pictures for it. Thanks.

Comment: @cu29p Indeed it appears that the looseness does not sufficiently explain the discrepancy. Maybe the core has different properties at different locations?

Comment: @tobalt I tested 8 core pieces, they all show low inductance for the litz wire coil. At this point I'm thinking the analyzer (70k€) is broken and isn't accurate for lowe series resistance.

Comment: @cu29p, as I suggested, take a solid (or normally-stranded) copper wire of **the same external diameter and outer isolation thickness**, and wind it on the same bobbin. Then measure.

Comment: Yes thank you. Once I get to the lab I should be able to measure it. My assumption is, it will act the same way as the litz coil.